# Org Mode ics export and date ranges

Tags: org-mode, org-export

When I use the ics export functionality of org-mode on org files which contain date ranges, i.e., entries like `<2016-08-20 Sat>--<2016-08-25 Thu>` only the first and the last day seem to be exported.

Is  there a way to export it so that the generated entry contains the whole date range?